# Dual boot Ubuntu with windows10

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue, windows-10, ubuntu-netbook, boot-partition

I've a old laptop with 500 GiB SATA HDD (blank) and 4GiB RAM. And I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 and windows 10. By giving 50 GiB for Windows and remaining to Linux. I've setup a 50GiB NTFS for win, 101 GiB /, 10GiB swap, 40MiB EFI boot, and remaining for /home. But after installation the Ubuntu goes to grub rescue mode. Now as I don't have any data in it, I'm going to reinstall Linux, but now which partitions do I need to set up? As there are so many operations like /recovery, /home, /, fat16, /fat32, /windows, /dos, etc.

Comment: Do not re-install anything yet! Instead, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from an emergency/live boot disk. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I'm afraid, I've already installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 and have created following partitions. 100 GiB /, 15 GiB /swap, 50 GiB empty (for windows), and remaining for /home. And have installed Windows and now both of my OS does work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this way to install my ubuntu 14.04 next to my windows 10 on my 750 gig laptop

install windows 10 like normal (taking the whole hard drive )
then insert the ubuntu disk/usb you have and start in try ubuntu (important!)
after that launch the desktop install and select install nexto windows or do your partitions manually (which i havent tried)
next when the install is finished do not reboot right away, open up your terminal and type:

```
sudo su
apt-get install efibootmgr 
efibootmgr
```

and then make sure that ubuntu is first boot, you might need to edit that in your BIOS, after that you are good to go :)